# Problem updating fields in Django app

Tags: python, sql, django

I am trying to create a new website with Django.  I am only just starting out with web development however and am new to many bits and pieces e.g. SQL.

I defined a model with various fields and then went ahead and created an instance of it etc in the Django shell.  Later I changed the name of a few of the fields, now when I try to do things with my model like Post.objects.all() I get errors such as:

```
DatabaseError: no such column: posts_post.body
```

How can I update my database entries (or just delete them) so I can get get on with my site?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for that has a name, [South](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/index.html), I use south for all my django sites! it is really useful and easy to use after you got used to it! give it a shoot!

using south to migrate that table you will need to run 2 commands:

First, to create the migrate script:

```
python manage.py schemamigration posts --auto
```

Afterwars to actual apply the table changes:

```
python manage.py migrate posts
```

Answer (score 2):

You added new attribute with name "body" to your model "Post" of your application "posts". Django cant't automatically create database column for this new field (it can only create database table for new model). So you need to  create all new fields manually. Alter your table in database:

```
ALTER TABLE `posts_post` ADD COLUMN `body` Text;
```

Comment: where do i run these sort of commands?  I'm guessing not in the python shell?

Comment: of course not in python shell, what database do you use? sqlite or mysql?(and if you just renamed your field then query must be "ALTER TABLE 'posts_post' CHANGE COLUMN `comment` `body` Text;")

Comment: i am using sqlite.  how do proper websites get around this sort of thing?  they must have to rename variables etc from time to time?

Comment: Almost certainly the wrong approach in development, and dangerous in production. In dev, zap the db and run syncdb again, or use South. In production, use South

Comment: for sqlite i use firefox addon"sqlite manager"(https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). You just add it into your browser, launch from browser menu, select your database(standart file dialog) and then you will see all your tables and will be able to do SQL queries. But anyway you should read a bit about SQL

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly haven't run `manage.py syncdb` since adding that field to your model.

If you ran syncdb and then added the field to your model, you will need to delete the table and start again with syncdb.

Alternatively, install South since it does this sort of schema upgrading for you.

Comment: I certainly did run syncdb.  I think the problem is not that I added a new field, but that I changed the name of certain fields, e.g. 'body' used to be 'comment'.

Answer (score 0):

manage.py syncdb doesnt deals with existing models though it creates table for 
new models . For this u can use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) 
after installing south run 
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto  (for existing models)
or 
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial (for new models)
and then
python manage.py migrate myapp

After using South you will not able to run manage.py syncdb for creating models
and south makes a directory where  it stores the migration files

When you next time setup the app, you have to run python manage.py migrate to make the tables for models in the database